# Soft coding dates in HIVE

Tags: date, hive, counting

I am having a difficult time soft coding dates in HIVE.
I want to do a count of unique ID's the appear in each week of my data.

e.g.

```
SELECT    
Count(distinct ID)    
From Database.Table    
Where filter1 = "Thing1" And filter2 = "Thing2"    
AND TO_DATE(timestamp_utc) between TO_DATE("2016-04-10") AND TO_DATE("2016-04-16")
```

But I want this not just for one week but for each week so far this year, without having to run it 20 times with different dates manually typed in.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter the data for the year,get the week number, group by id,week number

```
select count(distinct id) as id_count,weekofyear(TO_DATE(timestamp_utc)) as weeks
from Table
where filter1 = "Thing1" and filter2 = "Thing2" and TO_DATE(timestamp_utc) > '2016-01-01'
group by id,weeks
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me find a solution:

   select 
   count(distinct id) as id_count, weekofyear(timestamp) as week,  
   year(timestamp) as year
   from aws_d3.iaanalytics_detail
   where timestamp > '2016-01-27'
   AND name = "Event"
   group by year(TO_DATE(timestamp)), weekofyear(TO_DATE(timestamp))
   order by year, week

Comment: @DickMcManus Glad it helped